# Cannot use fetch to make a requst to localhost in Nextjs middleware function

Tags: javascript, next.js, fetch, httprequest, middleware

I am trying to fetch data from my backend on port 3001 in nextjs middleware function. But I can't seem to make it work. When I try to fetch from an api online, it works. But from my localhost it doesn't. I want it to fetch from the localhost. What should I do here. Thanks.

The middleware:

```
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import type { NextRequest } from "next/server";

export async function middleware(request: NextRequest, response: NextResponse) {
  const url = "http://localhost:3001/";

  try {
    const response = await fetch(url);

    if (!response.ok) {
      throw new Error(`HTTP error! Status: ${response.status}`);
    }

    const data = await response.json();
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }

 
}

export const config = {
  matcher: "/dashboard",
};
```

The Error:

```
[TypeError: fetch failed] {
   cause:  [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 0.0.0.0:3001] {
   errno: -111,
   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
   syscall: 'connect',
   address: '0.0.0.0',
   port: 3001
 }
```